# How do you deal with non-fast-forwardable situations in the git rebase workflow?

Tags: git, workflow, rebase

I have been reading about `git rebase` and the advantage of using a rebase workflow instead of a merge workflow. (I haven't actually been in the situations below as I am new to git)

I have read that one of the standard workflows for projects with multiple contributors is for the contributor to regularly regularly `rebase` their topic branch with the master branch of the "main (central/truth/canonical) repository". Rebasing before making a pull request leads to merges becoming fast-forwards.

While this part of it makes sense to me, I see many situations where merges will not be fast forwards. I want to know what happens in these situations. Does the project master (the owner of the canonical branch) pull the topic branch onto a local branch, `rebase` and `merge` (to ensure it remains a fast forward) or does the project manager just  make a non-fast-forward `merge`?

Once a contributor rebases and pushes his/her topic branch to a public repository, pushing a second `rebase` is not possible. What happens if those reviewing the contribution want to  see some of the code refined/tweaked before merging? The master branch would probably have changed by the time the contributor makes the fixes and the contributor cannot `rebase` since that would mean rewriting the history of a public repository.

Another situation where a fast-forward won't be possible would be when multiple submissions are made before the project manager can merge any into the master branch. While the first merge will be a fast forward, the remaining will not.

*To summarize my question:* What happens in situations where the branch that needs to be pulled in not based on `master` and cannot be rebased by the contributor? Does the project manager do the rebasing himself/herself before merging or does he/she just make a non-fast-forward merge?

Comment: So are you wondering how to handle if a branch was made and rebased into master, but someone later decided that they wanted to _undo_ the rebase, _after additional commits were made,_ and fix a couple more things and than rebase it back in?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you mean by *undo* the rebase. But, in the situation you described, the contributor will not be able to push their revised work to a public repository because that would require a `git push --force`. So my question is whether the project manager should make a non-fast-forward merge or whether do the rebasing himself/herself and then make a merge (which will be a fast forward).

Comment: If the branch has already been rebased back into main, _and changes made_, why not just have the contributor make a new _fixes_ branch off the current master and the manager can rebase it in when its ready?

Comment: Exactly. That was my question: should the *manager* have to rebase the *contributor's* changes or is it simpler/better/preferable for the manager to do a non-fast-forward merge (or there a third alternative)? I'm going to wait and see if there are any other answers. If you put that in an answer and there aren't any better solutions, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way GitHub has solved this problem is by allowing contributors:

- to have their own repo on the server side ("[fork](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/)") where they can `git push --force` at their heart's content)
- to propose patches ([pull requests](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/)) to the main repo (not branches, only commits to be applied or not), and that in a way for the maintainer to easily see if those patches can be applied in a fast-forward manner or not.

In the case where a fork isn't possible, you mention:

> Once a contributor rebases and pushes his/her topic branch to a public repository, pushing a second rebase is not possible.

Pushing should be possible, maybe by deleting your published branch first, and re-creating it by pushing it again.
As long as said branch has been rebased on top of the canonical branch, the new branch will be able to be "fast-forward" merged.

More generally, the maintainer is rarely the one doing the work of solving non-trivial merges: if there is no fast-forward step in sight, he/she will simply reject that branch and will ask the contributor for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of questions there. I'll toss in my two cents to say that I can't think of a single scenario that rebasing can't convert to a straight-line, fast-forwardable graph. It may take more or less work, depending on how the commits lie, but it should always be possible. If you can give specific scenarios that you think wouldn't be rebasable, maybe I or someone else can work out how you would do it.

Comment: My question is not about the actual `rebase` command not being possible. My question is about what happens in situations where the project manager cannot simply pull into `master` and have a fast forward.

Comment: @Umang: If you mean because he has local commits on master: `git pull --rebase`

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler for everyone if the contributor got the *new* `master` and put his fixes in a new branch. This would allow the manager to quickly do a FF merge and be done with it.  If the managers are like mine, that'll be the closest they get to the actual source:)